# Cassandra MemtableColumnCount

Tags: cassandra

When updating the same column data the MemtableColumnCount increases whereas it should be an earlier column value in memtable should be overwritten.
If I am updating the same column value 1000 times the MemtableColumnCount also increases to 1000.

Does anyone have any idea why we have a separate entry in Memtable for each update.

Regards,
Varun

Answer (score 0):

I think the following docs might help answer your interesting question:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_manage_ondisk_c.html explains that Cassandra avoids a read-before-write and never overwrites a row in place. To avoid a read-before-write, the storage engine groups inserts/updates to be made, and sequentially writes only the updated parts of a row in append mode.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_wt3_32w_zj__logging-writes-and-memtable-storage says the commit log receives every write made to a Cassandra node . . . The memtable is a write-back cache of data partitions that Cassandra looks up by key.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_update_c.html explains that during the update, if multiple versions of the column exist in the memtable, Cassandra flushes only the newer version of the column to disk . . .